# Android Studio. Сломанный шрифт

Tags: windows

Спасибо за помощь. Всем привет, установил Android Studio с офф. сайта, открываю его в первый раз и наблюдаю странности с шрифтом[image]

Comment: А если качнуть чё-нить от JetBrains - там тоже будет такая каша?

Comment: нет, JetBrains IDE, все нормально

Comment: Под другим пользователем так же?